# Get Array Value In JQuery through database

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Apple",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];

alert(availableTags);
});
```

here the value is passed by hardcode. but i want a 
availableTags this value through database

```
dbProdMgmtEntities context= new dbProdMgmtEntities();

            var getvalueofproduct = (from p in context.tblProducts
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         p.Title 
                                     }).ToArray();
            ViewBag.locations = getvalueofproduct;
```

this get array value and this value in my jquery code.

Comment: you must do a ajax call to get the tags.

Comment: How can i use ajax. have you any idea or Code for that...?

Comment: Or you can use this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/